# Function has a return type of 'Future<String>' but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a Future method in Dart (flutter). It simply runs a query on Firebase and returns the result. But even before writing my business logic, I am getting a warning message says:

> [dart] This function has a return type of 'Future', but
>   doesn't end with a return statement. [missing_return]

Below is my Future function:

```
Future<String> getLikeCount(documentID) async {
    Firestore.instance.collection('favorites').where(documentID).getDocuments().then((data){
      return 'test';
    });  
  }
```

I get the basic idea of why the error is happening, I assume that because there is a 'then' inside, till it happens the function returns nothing. How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `await` instead of `then` because your method is `async`

```
 final snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('favorites').where(documentID).getDocuments();
 return "test";
```

Change this :

```
 _getLikes() async
```

To this :

```
 Future<String> _getLikes() async
```

Because you expect a `String` `Future`.

Comment: right. But I still have the below error during run time:

type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: `_getLikes() async {
    var likes = await ArticleServices().getLikeCount(widget.post.documentID);
    return likes;
  }`

FYI, this is how I call the function

Comment: change var likes  to String likes

Comment: No luck. Still have the warning message during runtime:

'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: what is the return type of getLikeCount  ? , is your method getLikeCount async?

Comment: Yes getLikeCount is async as you can see in my question.

Comment: change this : _getLikes() , to this  Future<String> _getLikes()  async

Answer (score 2):

try this without async

```
Future<String> getLikeCount(documentID) {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('favorites').where(documentID).getDocuments().then((data){
      return 'test';
    });  
  }
```